# ios set background of a UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview

If you have seen the mailbox app you can swipe cells left and right and they have a UIView underneath that like green with a checkmark or whatever. I want to do this same thing. I have a tableView with custom cells that have gesture recognizers to animate/swipe them left and right but I can't figure out how to place a background underneath them. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might work if you add the subview and then bring the cell's content view above it, and then slide the content view over.

You could also just have a mask that clips the the visibility of your button container, and then animate the size of the mask so that it becomes visible as your cell content slides away.

You would want to add the container on the swipe before the animation starts, and then remove it after the animation stops when hiding it.

If placing it beneath the content view doesn't work, then use the mask, which will.

Comment: Animating the contentView worked great. You also have to play around with all the different background colors as well to see what's happening.